# How to replace the value of a specific column upon matching a different column in the same row

Tags: shell, awk, sed

sed -e '/\$FileCreateMode/ s/^/#/'  /etc/rsyslog.conf

echo '$FileCreateMode 0640' >> /etc/rsyslog.conf

How can I merge the above two commands into one command?

Comment: what's the initial `$FileCreateMode` value?

Comment: the  $FileCreateMode may not even exist in the file. It may be anything if it does.

Comment: the title is unclear *in a specific column after matching a different column*

Comment: Hopefully this heading sounds more relevant

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
FileCreateMode=what_you_want;sed -i "/$FileCreateMode/s/^/$FileCreateMode 0640\n#/" /etc/rsyslog.conf
```